# What array types CANNOT be supplied for T when constructing an ArrayList<T> collection?

Tags: java, arraylist

From what I understand, Objects can be supplied for T, but are there any array types that cannot be supplied for T collection?

Comment: Wrong. An `ArrayList<int[]>` can be instantiated with no problem at all... You are maybe confused with a generic array?

Answer (score 1):

All array types are subclasses of `Object` so you can use any array type in a generic which `extends Object` as `T` does by default, even arrays of primitive.